# Get absolute co-ordinates in MPandroid chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using the [MPAndroid](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) charting library.

Suppose I use the following code to get the point (x,y)

```
RectF rectF = mChart.getBarBounds(entry);
float x = rectF.centerX();
float y = rectF.centerY();
```

As fas as I understand, here the points are relative to the canvas on which the chart is being drawn.

How do I get the absolute co-ordinates of the same point on my screen ?

I did try the [Tranformer](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/730e5d3d9b63eb75da3aef8bac1c71cfbdf96222/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/utils/Transformer.java) class the library provides but was not able to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used getLocationInWindow to get the top-left position of the chart and converted the canvas position to screen position as follows :

```
int[] loc = new int[2];
yourChartView.getLocationInWindow(loc);
screenX = (int) (canvasPositionX + loc[0]);
screenY = (int) (canvasPositionY + loc[1]);
```